# MapInfo legend editing for right to left text

Tags: mapinfo, legend, internationalization, arabic

I work with some right to left text (Arabic, Hebrew) and I would like the legend to be from right to left instead of the current left to right. 
Is there any way of doing this in MapInfo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think MapInfo allows you to customize legends in the way you need. Still, you can "tease" the layout by deleting all text in the legend and then using text box on the side (same with legend title), as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I figured I could also just edit it in any photo editing software and just more the objects around.

Answer (score 2):

(I think this could go as another question: "How to remove black border around legend?")
Just select the legend in the layout and then click the region style: there you can change borders and also able/disable the foreground.

[image]