# Alignment of the contents of a legend in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, legend

Is it possible to change the alignment of the numbers of the ranges in a legend in MapInfo? (without having to "tease" the layout with a text box on top as in "[MapInfo legend editing for right to left text](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178232/55795)" )

I get this:

[image]

... where I would like to get this:

[image]

Comment: If you have MapInfo Pro, there is a [video tutorial](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/education/video-tutorials/detail/the-legend-designer-window-in-mapinfo-professional-11.5/) showing how to align items using a grid.

Comment: Mine looks like your second image by default but I'm using a point (.) as a digit grouping symbol. You seem to be using some other character - is that a space or a tab?

Comment: It is a space that comes up by default. I am using version 10, so unfortunately I don't have the legend designer window of 11.5.

Comment: You can change the Legend text to show a point in stead of a space - I think that would change the alignment, too

Comment: I changed the default spaces for points, but it doesn't modify the alignment. In fact, the lowest range in my example didn't reach the thousands, nor did it have spaces/points and showed the same alignment problem.